# PhoneGap do not refresh apps

Tags: rest, jquery-mobile, cordova, restful-authentication

I am using PhoneGap to call server services (RESTFuls) from another domain but when I close a session and enter to another I can still seeing the values for the first session, so the server calls are not being executed, this problem gets fixed once I clean the cookies on the device and only happens with Android OS 3 and 2.
Is there a way to make PhoneGap let the app to do the server call everytime the page is loaded or a way to refresh the pages?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a good way, but I added a parameter to the REST calls so the call will be:
var uniqueId = +(new Date),
var restURL = restURL + "?uniqueId" + uniqueId